# Reset scroll on a div having property overflow x or y

Tags: javascript, html

Suppose I have a div which is scrollable having property overflow-x or y.
I want to know how can I track it using onScroll method. What if I want the to revert the scroll. suppose a users scrolled 100px left and I want to revert that scroll. How do I achieve it. I am using react. No jquery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just run this.

```
var e = document.getElementById("myDiv");
e.scrollTop = 0;
```

You can also put it in a function and call it with the onscroll attribute.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrolltop.asp

Comment: This link was very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use **window.scrollY or window.scrollX**.

*Other way of doing*

```
var scrollLeft = (window.pageXOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageXOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollLeft;
var scrollTop = (window.pageYOffset !== undefined) ? window.pageYOffset : (document.documentElement || document.body.parentNode || document.body).scrollTop;
```

Comment: You know you can format code by putting 4 spaces before the line? You can also click the code button to automatically do that

Comment: Thanks  Abraham Murciano Benzadon